# Angular 1.5 Components with Form and $setPristine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to use a form within a component in Angular 1.5

I have the form working, in that I have model binding and can get to the data on submit. So I'm 90% of where I want to be, what's missing is being able to reset the form correctly using $setPristine.

I've attempted a couple of approaches the first was passing in the form as an argument to the reset function.

form.html

```
<form name="$ctrl.userForm">
  ...
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.reset($ctrl.userForm)" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

form.component.js

```
ctrl.reset = function(userForm) {
    ctrl.user = {};
    userForm.$setPristine // Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
};
```

[Full code in Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0mqPcq6gwav9JKQkgkfP?p=preview)

I also tried declaring $ctrl.userForm as an empty object $onInit, but that didn't seem to work either. With the $setPristine line removed the reset works in clearing the forms data but not it's state from an angular perspective.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your plunkr you have the entire component declared bellow.

```
function formController() {
  var ctrl = this;
  ...

  ctrl.reset = function(userForm) {
    ctrl.user = {};
    userForm.$setPristine
  };

  ctrl.reset();
}
```

The error is originated from this line `ctrl.reset();` where you call the method without sending the argument `userForm`. Also, you are using `$setPristine` in the wrong way and you don't have to pass the form as an argument either.

I sugest you to use the form declared on your controller like so:

```
angular
  .module('application')
  .component('mkForm', {
    templateUrl: 'form.html',
    controller: formController
  });

function formController() {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.master = {};

  ctrl.update = function(user) {
    ctrl.master = angular.copy(user);
  };

  ctrl.reset = function() {
    ctrl.user = {};
    ctrl.userForm.$setPristine();
  };
}
```

> **Note:** you don't have to call `ctrl.reset();` because the pristine state is the default state.

Comment: Thanks Lenilson, was causing me a lot of head scratching. Seemed so close to getting it working

Comment: @Mike you're welcome mate! Remember, angular is like math (were built to simplify), if it's causing you head scratching you're probably over complicating things. Cheers :{D